# Send data to Main Activity using Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I have a task where I need to receive a data from an EditText from the second activity and set it as as a TextView text in the main Activity, but my solution does not work. It never goes to the second activity on a click of a button and the text in a textview just disappears, since there is no passed data on the second Activity. Here is a code snippet:

```
// MainActivity
private static final int MY_REQUESTCODE = 17762;
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val requestCode = 1
    button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUESTCODE)
    }


}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == MY_REQUESTCODE){
        val transferredData = data?.getStringExtra("name")
        textView.text = transferredData

    }
}
```

}

and the second one:

```
// SecondActivity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
    intent.putExtra("name", name.text.toString())
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    finish()
}
```

}

Comment: Does your EditText on SecondActivity already have the text there at the time the activity is created?

Comment: No, it has a hint when in the beginning

Comment: I just edited your code and replaced `if requestCode == requestCode` which is always true with `requestCode == MY_REQUESTCODE`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing the request code. Better create a static variable for request code. For example

```
public static String REQUEST_CODE_MY_ACTIVITY = 1

button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_MY_ACTIVITY)
    }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MY_ACTIVITY){
        val transferredData = data?.getStringExtra("name")
        textView.text = transferredData

    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Your EditText doesn't have anything to return. You should create a Button, and return result after you have filled your EditText.

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        button2.setOnClickListener {

            intent.putExtra("name", name.text.toString())
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            finish()
        }

    }
}
```

Edit:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hello"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val requestCode = 1
        button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
        }


    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == requestCode){
            val transferredData = data?.getStringExtra("name")
            textView.text = transferredData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't' change the text of the textview :(

Comment: Did you type into the EditText with id = "name" then click on the Button with id = "button2". Because I have just created and run it normally!

Comment: https://github.com/beighth/sample I uploaded the whole project here, if you have some time, please take a look because I cannot find an error and it drives me nuts

Comment: @Dato.Beriashvili In your SecondActivity, `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)` you forgot to pass `intent`. It is different from what you posted :D